# What are the changes for programmatically accessing Office 2010 documents (a.k.a Office 14)?

Tags: sdk, office-2007

What are the changes for programmatically accessing Office 2010 documents (a.k.a Office 14)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little early.

You can try getting in on the Technical Preview.  [Sign up here.](https://microsoft.crgevents.com/Office2010TheMovie/Content/Home.aspx)